# How to concatenate a value from a dictionary with a string

Tags: swift

Given the following, what is the proper way to concatenate

```
var sets = [[ "reps": 10, "weight": 100 ], [ "reps": 10, "weight": 100 ], [ "reps": 10, "weight": 100 ]]
var text = sets[0]["reps"] + " reps"
```

The only thing that worked was the code below, but I don't understand why. Ideally I can simply use string interpolation for this, but that seems to generate a syntax error.

```
var text = sets[0]["reps"]!.description + " reps"
```

Comment: Do not use `description`, it is for debugging and the output is not guaranteed no to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Updated for  Swift 2*

`sets` is of type `[[String : Int]]`. So in order to get a `String` from your `Int`, you have to use [string interpolation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID292) or use a `String` initializer.

According to your needs, you may choose one of the following Playground examples:

### Optional binding + `String` initializer:

```
let sets = [[ "reps": 10, "weight": 100 ], [ "reps": 10, "weight": 100 ], [ "reps": 10, "weight": 100 ]]
if let int = sets[0]["reps"] {
    let text =  String(int) + " reps"
    print(text) // prints: "10 reps"
}
```

### Optional binding + string interpolation:

```
let sets = [[ "reps": 10, "weight": 100 ], [ "reps": 10, "weight": 100 ], [ "reps": 10, "weight": 100 ]]
if let int = sets[0]["reps"] {
    let text =  "\(int)" + " reps"
    print(text) // prints: "10 reps"
}
```

### Optional forced unwrapping:

```
let sets = [[ "reps": 10, "weight": 100 ], [ "reps": 10, "weight": 100 ], [ "reps": 10, "weight": 100 ]]
let int = sets[0]["reps"]! // Use forced unwrapping with caution
let text =  "\(int)" + " reps"
print(text) // prints: "10 reps"
```

Comment: I see, so it looks like string interpolation in swift is limited to just variables and other basic operations. It cannot handle more complex expressions. I come from Ruby where it is table stakes. Thanks for the help :).

Answer (score 1):

`sets[0]["reps"]` is an int. You can use formatting to specify the types:

```
var weight = sets[0]["reps"]!
var text = String(format: "%d reps", weight)
```

or all in one:

```
var text = String(format: "%d reps", sets[0]["reps"]!)

println("text: \(text)") // text: 10 reps
```